# Highcharts: how to group data points and display the total accordingly?

Tags: highcharts

I am new to Highcharts. I need to display a line chart.

Here is the categories:

```
 ["9/7/14", "9/8/14", "9/9/14", "9/10/14", "9/11/14", "9/12/14", "9/13/14", "9/14/14", "9/15/14", "9/16/14", "9/17/14", "9/18/14", "9/19/14", "9/20/14", ...]
```

Here is the data series:

```
[1, 4, 0, 2, 1, 1, 1, 5, 3, 1, 0, 0, 6, 8, ... ]
```

What I hope to achieve is to group every three dates and their total and display it accordingly. Something like this:

```
["9/7/14", "9/10/14", ...]
[5, 4, ... ]
```

Is this something Highcharts can do out-of-box and how if yes?

Thanks and regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible when using categories. When using categories, then you need to calculate this on your own.

In Highstock, that feature is called `dataGrouping` - however, doesn't work with categories.